# How can I force LaTeX to display my footnote on the same page as my foot note marker?

Tags: footnotes

I have placed a footnote on a particular page in my thesis, in a paragraph of a mathematical proof. However, LaTeX made it appear on the next page. I'm using the usual `\footnote{text}` command, without any footnote packages, and all my footnotes appeared on the same page as their footnote markers, except this particular one. I am using the command `\interfoonotelinepenalty=10000` in the preamble. For the record, the footnote fits on one line.

I noticed that this particular page ends with an end-of-proof marker `\qed`, which is displayed by the following commands in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \pushQED{\qed} \normalfont \topsep6 \p@\@plus6\p@ \relax \trivlist \item[\hskip \labelsep \sffamily \bfseries#1\@addpunct{}\hspace{2pt}] \ignorespaces} {\popQED \endtrivlist \@endpefalse \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
```

(I admit that I copy/pasted the above code from some website, and I modified it slightly to suit my needs, though I don't know exactly what's happening in this code.)

Is my footnote not appearing on the same page because of this code? If so, what can I do to force my footnote to be on the same page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Honestly, posting a MWE here would be impractical, as this happens at around page 150 of my thesis. All the other footnotes I have place themselves on the same page as the footnote marker. So I really do not know what to do. I might paste one chapter, but still, I would be pasting around 6 pages of stuff. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: the footnote is unlikely to be affected by _anything_ on an earlier page so you should be able to make a two page example that just has the paragraph with the bad break and some text like `a\\a\\a\\a\\a` to force that paragraph into the position on the page so it shows the bad break. The negative spacing in your code fragment looks highly suspicious but without a test example it's probably unreasonable for anyone to debug it.

Comment: If you want to remove the vertical space surrounding the proof, just replace  `\topsep6 \p@\@plus6\p@` with `\topsep\z@` (zero). Remove those wrong `\vspace` instructions.

Comment: the code you've quoted is derived in part from the `amsthm` package, but may or may not be appropriate if you're using a different theorem package.  if you *are* using the `amsthm` package, there are much better ways to get the qed box on the last line of the actual proof, and you should read the instructions.  regarding how the footnote is behaving, nobody is going to be able to help you without seeing at least what document class and packages you're using, preferably in the form of a compilable example.